# How to combine preprocessor/estimator selection with hyperparameter tuning using sklearn pipelines?

Tags: machine-learning, python, hyperparameter-tuning, pipelines

I'm aware of how to use `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline()` for simple and slightly more complicated use cases alike. I know how to set up pipelines for homogeneous as well as heterogeneous data, in the latter case making use of `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer()`.

Yet, in practical ML one must oftentimes not only experiment with a large set of model hyperparameters, but also with a large set of potential preprocessor classes and different estimators/models.

My question is a dual one:

1. What would be the preferred way to set up a pipeline where the selection of text vectorizers is treated as an additional hyperparameter for grid or randomized search?
2. Additionally, what would be the preferred way to set up a pipeline where the selection of multiple models can also be treated as an additional hyperparameter? What about optimizing the model-specific hyperparameters in this case?

In the first case a common use case is text vectorization: treating the choice of `CountVectorizer()` or `TfidfVectorizer()` a hyperparameter to be optimized.

In the second case a practical use case could be selecting between various algorithms or in the case of multiclass classifications, whether to use `OneVsOneClassifier()` or `OneVsRestClassifier()`.

I understand that this might exactly be what AutoML solutions have been developed for. I heard of out-of-the-box AutoML solutions in the past that can do automatic model selection with hyperparameter tuning but I have no experience in any of them, thus I don't know if they indeed provide an answer for the general topics I described in this post.

Comment: I recently had this similar spirited [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684058/how-to-feature-select-scikit-transformers-within-featureunion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pure scikit approaches:

- When pre-processing relates to data balancing & sampling strategies, consider using [Imbalance-Learn](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/) components (ie: RandomUnderSample) you embed right into your pipelines. This lets you hyper tune the parameters.
- Rely on **passthrough** functionality of grid search when deciding if certain pre-processing steps are needed at all. This however cannot express when the step is a required pre-condition to another step (ie: StandardScaler + MLPerceptronClassifier)
- Consider using [scikit-opt](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/)'s **BayesSearchCV** strategy to walk through the parameter space based on previous runs rather than fixed or randomly like *GridSearchCV* or *RandomizedSearchCV* do. For many parameter tuning this may converge faster.

⚠️ In practice I find its often extremely time & computationally expensive to have full end-to-end pipelines that try to learn everything. (ie: parameters, metrics, model types, normalization stages, features, architectures, etc), so hyper tune what matters most.

Comment: That's very valuable feedback, particularly the part about the BayesSearchCV which I have been considering already to use but have never come across so far. Thanks a lot!